# Rails phrasing gem gives 500 error when updating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a page with an editable text box on my web page using the rails phrasing gem (https://github.com/infinum/phrasing). This works fine when I use a normal phrase with phrase('editable') however when I try to use it to edit a model attribute I am hit with two 500 errors when I try to submit the changes.

I have added the attribute to the whitelist and even when I change the config to whitelist everything I am still hit with the same error. The correct data is fetched from the database as it is displayed on the page correctly so I am unsure on what the issue could be here.

The code for the phrase is

```
= phrase(@pages, :content)
```

In the controller I am using

```
@pages = Page.where('location = ? AND topic = ?', @current_location, 'topic name').first
```

to get the correct record from the database

In config/initializers/phrasing.rb I have set
`config.allow_update_on_all_models_and_attributes = true` for testing purposes

The schema for pages is:

```
  create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "location"
    t.string "topic"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The error that I get in the network tab is:

```
Template is missing

Missing template phrasing_phrases/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/user/project/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/phrasing-4.2.1/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/devise_cas_authenticatable-1.10.3/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/devise-4.6.1/app/views"
```

Let me know if there is any other information that I should provide to help solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you run `rails generate phrasing`? also it seems your missing a template.  Which is the files in your `views` folder that your working with?

Answer (score 0):

How do you define `update` action in your controller?

I suppose you've override `PhrasingPhrasesController`

Try to return `redirect_to` in your `update` action.

```rb
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def update
    // Your code
    redirect_to page_path(@your_page)
  end
end
```

Comment: So I don't have an update action in my controller for this page. I assumed it would be something that I would the gem would handle.  The controller for this page only has a session variable and a query to the database:



`def topic_name
    @current_location = session[:current_location]
    @pages = Page.where('location = ? AND topic = ?', @current_location, 'topic_name').first
  end `